# Planting without soil & harm ideas: giving inspiration, motivation

Tags: right-view, sila, right-livelihood, right-intention

My person thought of motivating, encouraging each other in supporting the foundation for meditation, complete Sila incl. right livelihood, if bound to house-life, viewing on the aspects of, planting food **without soil & harm**.

Maybe some of you here like to share each other not only motivation like:

**Why could this be a good livelihood?**

**How could this be a good livelihood?**

but also tips in how to do practical and simple without much material need and high tech.

**How to do it for your own in least harmful way?**

If wishing to share it foremost dedicated to the Sangha and it's devoted Noble followers, to have a change of higher merits, one can use the dedicated place [here](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,9634.msg21210.html#msg21210) as well.

*(Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks... but for a way out of that wheel)*

Answer (score 2):

Samana(if I am not mistaken) , If by " without soil & harm" you mean "my traces of bad habbits should not be there in devotees" then stop making or even a desire to make others your student or student of any human( one who is not enlightened) cause as a student,  we tend to follow our master's habbits.  Dhamma(right teachings)  is only teacher.

Along with this,  stop writing, "(Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks... but for a way out of that wheel)" everytime cause it gives creepy feeling of " someone wants to steal-away your ideas/theory or might blame you in future". Act independently,  act naturally, don't  bother about anything.  Old age is only to enjoy the merits of young&hot blood times not to be bound by bad or evil.

Comment: How can/could my person help good householder Alex? Nyom seems to be gravely stressed.

Comment: Thanks!  You asked me that's  enough.  You don't  need to struggle for me(well! not now).  Hope you are good in your health(mental & physical).  My metta to you & your enviornment.

Comment: If struggling for someone, would that help another or oneself, good householder?

Comment: Giving a metaphor-like answer on growing in Dhamma without soil (Nissaya) is also fine, if Nyom likes to give a useful share for his fellows here.

Comment: No need for me atleast!  helping hands, if raised with healthy mind induces good vibrations in oneself & another.

Comment: If so, then good to modify your Introduction text.

Answer (score 0):

It all starts with food.

> [AN10.27:10.5](https://suttacentral.net/an10.27/en/sujato#an10.27:10.5): ‘All sentient beings are sustained by food.’ Becoming completely disillusioned, dispassionate, and freed regarding this one thing, seeing its limits and fully comprehending its meaning, a mendicant makes an end of suffering in this very life.

To live, we must eat. And since we have physical bodies, we need physical food. That food must also eat and is sustained by conditions. There is much food on the Earth, but if we allow greed to take it all, then we starve. And die.

Because the food we eat must itself also eat, we have to provide harmonious conditions for a sustained abundance of food. We need to understand and practice [permaculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permaculture), which is sustainable and ecologically aware agriculture.

And this brings us to the fifth peril of modern times:

> [AN5.80:6.2](https://suttacentral.net/an5.80/en/sujato#an5.80:6.2): In such conditions it can be expected that they will engage in storing up goods for their own use, and making obvious hints about digging the earth and cutting plants. This is the fifth future peril that has not currently arisen, but will arise in the future … These are the five future perils that have not currently arisen, but will arise in the future. You should look out for them and try to give them up.”

In many places today, humans practice slash and burn farming. Sometimes it  is blatant, as in the Amazon, where jungle is cleared for farmland. Sometimes it is subtle, where topsoil is consumed inexorably by imprudent and intensive farming. All these are unsustainable. Our children will starve.

But we can learn how to give back. We can learn how to sustain and feed the planet that feeds us. We can learn how to not to kill, not to slash and not to burn. We can all learn this. We all need to learn this. All of us need to understand this so that we can act for the greater good with awareness. This is not just about farmers and farming. This is a way of life for all of us to learn. With sustainable agriculture and gardening we can feed each other.

Try this one very simple, very difficult thing. Grow a plant that will feed you. It takes months to grow one head of broccoli. Try it. Try it with a friend. And when you understand how difficult this is to grow a single meal, you will deeply understand the heartbreaking importance of agriculture. It takes quite a long time and many helping hands to feed the world so it can feed us. Start now and help  feed the world. All the world. Not just humans. All the world.

Nurture the world or starve.

---

Regarding "planting without soil", I recommend Kratky hydroponics 
method with soil in netpots. But that really is a thread for Gardening SE. Interestingly, hydroponics does address the "do not dig" prohibition of the Vinaya, but harvesting is still problematic from a Vinaya point of view.

Discussions are beyond the scope of StackExchange. For those interested, I've started another thread at [SuttaCentral.net](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/growing-food-without-digging/14741)

Comment: Sadhu, so fare. maybe good to add that one uses most harmless food not to live at least, but to live on to escape the wheel of food and eater. May good householder feel welcome to share simple tips for simple people on the track to search for escape here:  http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,9634.0.html maybe soon some pictures of very simple ways, yet practical.

Comment: Indeed. This is an enormous and deep subject. I am myself but a student of permaculture. I was shocked at how hard it was to grow a single head of broccoli. Yet that struggle has inspired me to devote what life I have remaining towards understanding and supporting permaculture and wholesome food. Let us all reach out to each other and help with this. We cannot do this alone.

Comment: "Nurture the world or starve." isn't right. Nurture the world and you stay bond. Nurture what is worthy to nuture lead to escape and nothing to worry of those who are not to be shown that any food involvs harm for other.

Comment: Yes. You're right. Nurture the world or starve is incomplete. AN5.80 discusses four other perils. There is much much more to be aware of.

Comment: "Let us all reach out to each other and help with this.", get your way for 4000 monasteries, and millions of Buddhist with simple and practical solutions, leaving harmful hightech behind.

Comment: The flesh of the Son. Nyom might know it, should be leading, no matter whether the Son is traced in a beefsteak or in a tomato. Yet better ways are direct killing are useful, of cause.

Comment: At the very least, read the suttas and become inspired to walk the Noble Eightfold Path.

Comment: Would you follow those wakling or already done?

Comment: So, it's time to leave this food center here again. Much succes in leavong home!

Comment: "hydroponics does address the "do not dig" prohibition of the Vinaya, but harvesting is still problematic from a Vinaya point of view.", also kammical when already perceiving it a living being. There are, how ever, many householder, who don't perceive it that way, so for them such ways are great. A monk (Bhikkhu) of cause can not harvest. But actually they could plant, without breaking Vinaya or unskillful action, if looking not to let living being in the water, sink into soil and die. Much success with Nyoms undertakings, and if wishing to help out directly and very practical, he knows where.

Comment: My person suggest the Ashrams helper today, that he can lead experiments in the middle of the forest next the futur lay visitor hall, if good householder likes to give him assistance, as monastery sample, he may feel welcome.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. And how might one contact the Ashram's helper today in the middle of the forest to discuss experiments with hydroponics?

Comment: If other would do all efforts for one, where would the place for his own merits? People think often given is from above to below but great merits wouldn't work that way.

Comment: Maybe good householder wasn't that attentive, since shared already before: [ដាំដោយគ្មានដី ការចិញ្ចឹមជីវិតត្រឹមត្រូវ Planting without soil & harm Hydroponics](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,9634.msg21210.html#msg21210), one way, in just one case.

Comment: I posted on the newsgroup. http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,9634.15.html
I actually would recommend that monastics join a FB group such as https://www.facebook.com/groups/KratkyHydroponics/  since it was difficult to create informative posts on the sangham.net site

Comment: How could a monastic, if not alajji, if abstaining from not personaly given without strings, if not a householder in robes, ever join FB... and yes, own labor is harder then use others recources, rely on given is "harder" as to share taken, good householder. Also this is why there are small and great merits.

Comment: Alas, I have failed you. You will need to find your own answer. Please note that lotus flowers blossom in mud. FaceBook is just mud.

Comment: As if it would have been subjected for my person. Does Nyom think that it is proper to invest time in farming?. And yes, the Buddha askes one to come out of the mud first, leave home fist. It's like hydroponics. This area is called punna kiriya vatthu, the borderlands. Lotos also age, get sick and die in the mud.